# A bit lost... Jackson deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I've been working with Jackson to deserialize data. In general it's been a smooth process.

What has me stumped is trying to deserialize something that has a known amount of objects into a custom class when the JSON properties lack names.

Overall, I'm deserializing a map of objectId:fullObject

```
{
"1411842351335": {"vers": [], "name": "Basic (and reversed card)", "tags": [], "did": 1, "usn": -1, "req": [[0, "all", [0]], [1, "all", [1]]], "flds": [{"size": 20, "name": "Front", "media": [], "rtl": false, "ord": 0, "font": "Arial", "sticky": false}, {"size": 20, "name": "Back", "media": [], "rtl": false, "ord": 1, "font": "Arial", "sticky": false}], "sortf": 0, "latexPre": "\\documentclass[12pt]{article}\n\\special{papersize=3in,5in}\n\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\n\\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}\n\\pagestyle{empty}\n\\setlength{\\parindent}{0in}\n\\begin{document}\n", "tmpls": [{"afmt": "{{FrontSide}}\n\n<hr id=answer>\n\n{{Back}}", "name": "Card 1", "qfmt": "{{Front}}", "did": null, "ord": 0, "bafmt": "", "bqfmt": ""}, {"afmt": "{{FrontSide}}\n\n<hr id=answer>\n\n{{Front}}", "name": "Card 2", "qfmt": "{{Back}}", "did": null, "ord": 1, "bafmt": "", "bqfmt": ""}], "latexPost": "\\end{document}", "type": 0, "id": "1411842351335", "css": ".card {\n font-family: arial;\n font-size: 20px;\n text-align: center;\n color: black;\n background-color: white;\n}\n", "mod": 1411842351}}
```

Each object gets mapped into a [class](https://github.com/drbubbletea/openwebsrs/blob/master/openwebsrs-libanki/src/main/java/com/openwebsrs/libanki/entities/AnkiNoteType.java) with general structure that follows:

```
public class AnkiNoteType {
    ...
    private List<AnkiNoteTypeReq> req;
    ...
}
```

With the problematic object

```
package com.openwebsrs.libanki.entities;    
public class AnkiNoteTypeReq {
        ...
        private Integer a;
        private String b;
        private List<Integer> c;
        ...
    }
```

The problem I've been having here and in other situations is mapping a list of objects without names (that is, no "name:value" just "value") into a specified class.

```
"req": [[0, "all", [0]], [1, "all", [1]]]
```

What I've been doing can be seen [here in implementation](https://github.com/drbubbletea/openwebsrs/blob/master/openwebsrs-libanki/src/main/java/com/openwebsrs/libanki/services/impl/AnkiDeserializationServiceImpl.java) with important bits below:

```
@Override
public List<AnkiNoteType> getAnkiNoteTypes(String noteTypesString) throws IOException {
    Map<Long, AnkiNoteType> noteTypeMap = objectMapper.readValue(noteTypesString, new TypeReference<Map<Long, AnkiNoteType>>() {
    });
    return new ArrayList(noteTypeMap.values());
}
```

I don't need a full solution. I just need to get on the right track.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have any control over the format of the json? If so, I strongly recommend you choose to represent "req" as an array of objects instead of an array of arrays (which are actually objects). Not only would this solve your current problem, but also solve any future problems you may have should this json representation be expanded upon such that the fields are ambiguous.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The data is pulled directly from the database of another application (http://ankisrs.net/). Appreciate the idea though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Shape.html to ask Jackson to map directly to an array. In this mode, jackson requires you to annotate the order of the properties, and maps from a json array to an object.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! Will have to try both order-based deserialization and manual deserialization with JsonNode and figure out the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

If the individual items aren't using name value pairs, then you'll need to write some kind of custom deserializer that understands the relationship between the array offsets in this:

```
[0, "all", [0]]
```

And maps them to the properties in the `AnkiNoteTypeReq`.  I know there is a mechanism in Jackson where you can specify that a given type should be deserialized using a custom class, but I don't remember the exact syntax.  As a first pass I would use Jackson to deserialize the JSON string to a JsonNode and do manual deserialization by creating a function like

```
static AnkiNoteTypeReq fromJsonNode(JsonNode node) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! Will research into manually deserializing with JsonNode.